# use hooks inside function component with inject and observer - mobx

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to add `observer` to my component, but when I doing so I got error

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

without `observer` and just with `inject`, all works fine, but I need component to re-render while changes happen at store.

Am I writing syntax incorrectly, or should apply some workaround (like setting store object into local state and force re-rendering like that or refactor code to use `useStore` and `useObserver`)?

with `obserever` (not working)

```
export default inject(stores => stores)(
    observer(props => {
       ...component with hooks usage...
 }))
```

without `obserever`  (working but not re-rendering)

```
export default inject(stores => stores)(props => {
       ...component with hooks usage...
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, everything should work fine.

You need to check your `mobx-react` version though. Only version >= 6 works with hooks.